# Xcode refresh webView every time the tab is selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

I have the following code for a view which is one of the options attached to a tab on a Tab Bar Controller (swift 3):

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let str8REDURL = URL(string: "https://str8red.com/leaderboard/")
        let str8REDURLRequest = URLRequest(url: str8REDURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(str8REDURLRequest)

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

This is working perfectly.  However, the user can currently have a browse of the site and then select another tab.  When they select this tab I would like the webView to reload the URL as above, so basically resetting that view as if it had just loaded.  I am assuming there is some "reload" option but can't seem to work it out and would appreciate any guidance.

*UPDATE*

After a few suggestions I even tried the following with no joy:

```
func viewWillAppear() {
    let str8REDURL = URL(string: "https://str8red.com/leaderboard/")
    let str8REDURLRequest = URLRequest(url: str8REDURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(str8REDURLRequest)
}
```

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: So, you've already tryed the `webView.reload()` method ?

Comment: Not as of yet, I was guessing that it would be something like that but was unsure where to place it.

Comment: You can place in the `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: No joy, the webView does not reset :/

Comment: @AlanTingey your `viewWillAppear` function is wrong

Comment: Many thanks for help, indeed it was wrong.  I tried to fiddle with it and that went badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the load request in `viewWillAppear()`, it will be called everytime you change the tab back to that screen

Comment: No joy, the webView does not reset :/ do I need to tell it to refresh with a specific URL?

Comment: What did you put there? just put `webView.loadRequest(str8REDURLRequest)` in your `viewWillAppear`, it will reload the url again

Comment: your function is wrong, it's `override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) `, not `func viewWillAppear()`

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let str8REDURL = URL(string: "https://str8red.com/leaderboard/")
        let str8REDURLRequest = URLRequest(url: str8REDURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(str8REDURLRequest)
        
    }

Comment: hi. I have the same problem. how you solved this? here is my question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448746/refreshing-a-tab-bar-item-on-webview

Answer (score 1):

`webview.loadRequest()` will load the webview content. webview.reload() reloads the last request which has finished loading. Therefore for your case, you can use `webview.reload()`

Comment: No joy, the webView does not reset :/ do I need to tell it to refresh with a specific URL?

Comment: In this case, it will reload the above url, mentioned in your code

Comment: Then I am doing something wrong as it is not reloading.  Any ideas?

Comment: Connect your "webView" in storyboard as well. And then call, "webview.reload()" when new tab is pressed.

Comment: new tab opens another view controller or same?

Comment: Another view controller, it works in the first instance.  However, the user can then browse the site then click tab 1.  When they click tab 2 I want it to reset itself.

Comment: In another viewcontroller, it will be another webview. So you will have to connect it in storyboard as well, and then can call above 3 lines in "viewDidLoad"

Comment: Appreciate the assistance, got it working with the loadRequest option.