# refreshing a tab bar item on webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift3

I am newbie and need help. I built a webview app on xcode (swift), with tab bars. and I need to know, how can I refresh the tab bar, when I pressed it.

how can I refresh my tab bar item, when I pressed first tab bar item?
For example, twitter app. when you pressed first tab, it refreshes the wiew, and goes to main screen.

here is my code;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
let url = URL (string: "https://google.com")
        let webviewgo = URLRequest(url: url!)
        firstWebview.loadRequest(webviewgo)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

       super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       self. firstWebview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))

}
```

Comment: could you give details? must I delete viewDidLoad and write this function?

Comment: just comment it out, and try the answer above

Comment: The least difficult approach to fulfill this is to put your stacking code into viewWillAppear: rather than viewDidLoad. While viewDidLoad may just get called once, when your view is introduced, viewWillAppear: is called at whatever time your view controller is going to be exhibited, regardless of whether it be in the tab bar, in a route controller, and so on., which gives you a decent snare to execute stacking and format usefulness.

Comment: this answer is correct, tell your problem with this, not just im not professional and i got error, this code is for add below `viewDidLoad`